# How can I remove fast glue (Cyanoacrylate) from LEGO bricks?

Tags: glue

I recently bought some second-hand LEGO bricks. Some of these bricks have quick glue on them.

How can I get rid of the glue?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanoacrylate#Solvents_and_debonders) acetone can help soften cyanoacrylate, but it also [dissolves ABS](http://www.instructables.com/id/100-Warp-Free-MakerBot-3D-Printing/step1/Put-ABS-Scraps-and-Acetone-in-a-Jar/), so you might want to avoid that.

[Another website](http://www.howtocleanstuff.net/how-to-remove-super-glue-from-plastic-and-vinyl/) advises for using soap and water, although it seems dubious to me whether it would make any difference, this method certainly won't damage your parts (unless they are electronic or have stickers), so you might as well give it a try.

[Heating](http://www.permabond.com/blog/2009/07/09/adhesive-removal/) the CA can also soften it to ease removal, but beware that ABS is also susceptible to melting.

There are also [commercial products](http://www.caglue.com/Frequently-Asked-Questions-about-CA-glue-from-Satellite-City-Instant-Glues_ep_42.html#Solvent) designed to soften and remove CA glue from various surfaces, but you should always check whether they play nicely with the ABS or would they also soften your bricks.

As a last resort, however time consuming it might be, shaving the glue off using precision blades is a surefire way if you can work with such precision and have the required time. Using sandpaper and polishing after the process can save a bit of time though.